# How to use ncmli to set proto udp6 for openvpn

Tags: networkmanager, openvpn, ipv6

I am using kubuntu 20.04 LTS. Network connections are managed by NetworkManager. I am trying to set up a connection to an openvpn server that only has an IPV6 address. I think that "proto udp6" should be added to the openvpn client options (it is there on the server side). However, I cannot find such an option in the GUI, and neither do I know how to use nmcli to set it. Is there a solution?